# Why Can't I Call setAlpha on Icon in MenuItem

Tags: java, android, icons, drawable, menuitem

I have been stuck trying to simply change the transparency of this `MenuItem` icon for hours... I'm not sure what else to do. I am able to successfully call `setEnable()` on the icon, which means the problem is not accessing it. It must have something to do with the icon itself. I am using the standard Material theme that comes with the "Basic Activity Template", would a style or theme even prevent me from programmatically changing it? I am calling `onPrepareOptionsMenu` from a fragment, could that be the issue? Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    // top menu (action bar)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_searches, menu);

    // bottom menu (the one I am having an issue with)
    Menu bottomMenu = toolbarBottom.getMenu();

    // the MenuItem I am trying to call "setAlpha()" on
    deleteMenuItem = bottomMenu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);

    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < bottomMenu.size(); itemIndex++) {
        bottomMenu.getItem(itemIndex).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new
            MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        if (itemsChecked > 0) {
            deleteMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
            
            /* I have also tried "delete.getIcon().mutate().setAlpha(255);" -
- but I do not have another instance of the icon so I don't think I need to -
- call "mutate()". It didn't work anyways */
            deleteMenuItem.getIcon().setAlpha(255);

        } else {
            deleteMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
            deleteMenuItem.getIcon().setAlpha(5);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`menu.findItem()` is laggy and calling it within `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` produces bad user experience. It's better to get `MenuItem` object once while creating menu, and then just call `setAlpha` each time menu occures on screen. You can try

```
MenuItem mDynamicMenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    // Get dynamic menu item
    mDynamicMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    // Here is just a good place to update item
    MenuItem delete = mDynamicMenuItem.findItem(R.id.action_delete);

    if (itemsChecked > 0) {
        delete.setEnabled(true);
        delete.getIcon().setAlpha(255);

    } else {
        delete.setEnabled(false);
        delete.getIcon().mutate().setAlpha(5);
        delete.getIcon().setAlpha(5);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey Nonakun, thanks for the response but that did not solve my problem as of yet. I did ask you suggested and moved the `MenuItem.findItem()` call, but I am still not able to change the transparency of the MenuItem. Any suggestions?